# cURL error 7 failed to connect port 80 in Laravel

Tags: curl, guzzle, yahoo-api

I have called 3rd party yahoo/google API in my wordpress project using cURL wherein I am facing error regarding cURL error 7 connection failed . I have white listed the IP of yahoo API in wordpress.

Code from comments:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(); 
$from_Currency = substr($proj->currency, 0, 3); 
$to_Currency = $req->currency; 
$encode_amount = 1; 
$get = $client->get("google.com/finance/converter?a=$encode_amount&from=$from_Currency&to=$to_Currency"); 
$get = explode("<span class=bld>",$get); 
$get = explode("</span>",$get[1]); 
$converted_currency = preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/", null, $get[0]); 
return $converted_currency;
```

Comment: Post a code example.

Comment: Also clarify where you are doing this call. Is it in a Page, Post, Template, Plugin. Are you using any hooks to make the call?

Comment: Also, does the call work on the same computer outside of Wordpress?

Comment: $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$from_Currency = substr($proj->currency, 0, 3);
                $to_Currency = $req->currency;
                $encode_amount = 1;
                $get = $client->get("https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=$encode_amount&from=$from_Currency&to=$to_Currency&format json");
$get = explode("<span class=bld>",$get);
$get = explode("</span>",$get[1]);
$converted_currency = preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/", null, $get[0]);
return $converted_currency;
I have written this code in my Laravel controller function

Comment: I don't see yahoo in the example. I do see google. Why isn't it with `https://`?

Comment: `google.com/finance/… json` - is not a valid URL, is it really what you have?

Comment: THis is the URL that I have used for google finance
https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=$encode_amount&from=$from_Currency&to=$to_Currency
and for yahoo I have used
query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20rate%2Cname%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.finance.yahoo.com%2Fd%2Fquotes%3Fs%3DUSDNGN%253DX%26f%3Dl1n'%20and%20columns%3D'rate%2Cname'&format=json
but getting same cURL error 7 in both the APIs